# Changing the default location of Receiving files of bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-s-4, files

Hi I am user of Samsung Galaxy S4, I want to know how can I change the default location of the Received files to SD Card instead of the phone storage?

Comment: You may not be able to. It depends on the Application you are using, and if it is just the default way it depends if the OEM has exposed the Bluetooth path and allow it to be modified. As far as I can tell you can't on an S4. It won't change on mine through the settings OR in an app that I wrote.

Comment: so sad...:( so can any app does that...
:(